# How to convert XML to HTML using c# dynamically

Tags: c#

How to upload XML file and generate Html file without XSLT file using C#...

Comment: What does your XML look like? What do you want it to look like as HTML? We need more information.

Answer (score 3):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is one option. See also: [Generating HTML using LINQ](http://devlicio.us/blogs/vinull/archive/2008/08/03/using-linq-to-generate-html.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little open-ended, but you might consider just writing a program that:

1. Deserializes the XML.
2. Having read in the XML, format the text.
3. Output the text using the standard in/out libraries in C#.

I don't know if this is the most efficient solution -- but I think it would work.